# Express each of the following statements using quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Let F(x, y) be the statement x can fool y. Where the universe of discourse is the
set of all people in the world**

1. (a) Everybody can fool Gavin.
2. (b) Everybody can fool somebody.
3. (c) No one can fool everybody.
4. (d) There is someone who can’t be fooled by anyone.
5. (e) No one can fool themselves.

---

Here is my attempt. I just want to confirm which is correct and which isn't. Thank you!

1. a) ∀x F(x, Gavin)
2. b) ∀x ∃y F(x, y)
3. c) ¬∀x ∀y F(x, y)
4. d) ∀x ∃y ¬[F(x, y)]
5. e) ¬∀x ∃x F(x, x)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are correct.

3. No one can fool everybody. That is, there does not **exist** someone who can fool everybody, so should be $\neg \ \exists x \ \forall y \ F(x,y)$. Your answer translates to 'not everyone can fool everyone' which is different.
4. There **is** someone who can’t be fooled by anyone. So should be $\exists y \ \forall x \ \neg \ F(x,y)$. Your answer means 'everyone has a person they cannot fool'
5. No one can fool themselves. Simply $\forall x \ \neg F(x,x)$. It doesn't make sense to apply two different quantifiers to the same variable.

Comment: Ahh, I was getting confused between the order. 
And the 2nd expression on no. 5 was a typo, haha
Thank you very much!